# How to create proxy list that has every second element of original list?

Tags: kotlin

I need a wrapper list that reflects all changes of an original list like `subList()` but contains only every second element.

I tried:

```kotlin
fun getWrapperList (original_list: List<T>): List<T> = 
   IntRange(0, original_list.size.div(2)).map { original_list[it * 2 + 1] }
```

But it creates a new list that doesn't reflects changes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything in the standard library for this, as it's not a common requirement.  (The only times I can remember wanting to access alternate elements, I should have refactored the code to a list of sub-objects instead…)

But you can create your own easily enough.

The simplest way is probably by extending [`AbstractList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-abstract-list/), e.g.:

```
class AlternateView<T>(val sourceList: List<T>): AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size get() = (sourceList.size + 1) / 2

    override fun get(index: Int) = sourceList[index * 2]
}
```

(That gives the first, third, fifth… items; I'm sure you can see how to tweak it if you want the others.  Or make that a constructor param and support both.)

That works as required, with changes to the original list reflected in the view:

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val view = AlternateView(list)
println("list=$list, view=$view") // list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], view=[1, 3, 5]

list[0] = 7
list.removeAt(1)
list.add(4, 8)
println("list=$list, view=$view") // list=[7, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6], view=[7, 4, 8]
```

If performance matters, you should probably look at overriding more of the `AbstractList` methods, or even implementing [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) directly.  But that could be a lot of work, and this simple version should suffice in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like following (using `computed` property)

```
class SomeClass {
    val originalList = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

    val derivedList: List<Int>
        get() = originalList.filterIndexed { index, i -> index % 2 == 0 }
}

fun main()  {
    val someClass = SomeClass()
    println(someClass.originalList)
    println(someClass.derivedList)

    someClass.originalList.add(7)
    println(someClass.derivedList)
}
```

Above generates output of

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: I don't think that's not a proxy list, in the sense that if you call `someClass.derivedList` and keep a reference to the result, that reference won't reflect any later changes as mentioned in the question.